# coverage.py: Why the expected lines are not marked green in html report?

Tags: python, code-coverage, coverage.py

Sample code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys
from coverage import Coverage

class Cover_Diy(object):

    def cover_diy(self, cmd):
       if cmd == "hostname":
           os.system(cmd)
       elif cmd == "uptime":
           os.system(cmd)
       else:
           os.system(cmd)


def main(args):
    covd = Cover_Diy()
    covd.cover_diy(args[1])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cov = Coverage()
    print dir(cov)
    cov.start()
    args = sys.argv
    try:
       sys.exit(main(args))
    except Exception as ex:
       print ex
    cov.stop()
    cov.html_report(directory="/home/username/scripts/html")
```

The code is executed using this command:
python sample.py hostname

**Problem**: 
 Lines 3,4,5,7,9,10,11,18 are marked as missing which means not executed, why is that so?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vy2A0.png)

Comment: The code here doesn't match the code in the image.

Comment: Sorry, for that confusion. Will definitely take care next time but I think this time it was just variable name mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

Your `def` and `class` lines are executed when the file is run. This happens before you start coverage on line 23.  Coverage can't observe execution that happens before it is started.

You'll need to separate the code that runs coverage from the code you want coverage to measure.  I'm not sure what the goal of this program is. Usually it's simpler to just use the coverage command line to run an existing Python program, and not use the coverage API at all.

Comment: Thanks for the response, basically this is a sample program but my idea to collect code coverage for an in house python-based service. The problem I faced for coverage is similar and for service, I can not use command line effectively I have to use APIs since I have thousands of tests to executed.